# Spark 3.4.0 with maven compiles but fails at run time

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

This simple Scala code compiles and runs fine with SBT but fails at runtime with Maven (compiles OK)

The following describes the artefact versions

```
Host: RHES 7.6
Spark version 3.4.0
Apache Maven 3.9.2 (c9616018c7a021c1c39be70fb2843d6f5f9b8a1c)
Java version: 11.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /opt/jdk-11.0.1
Scala version on the host:
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.13.8 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

This code as attached compiles fine with maven

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.time._

object ReduceByKey {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

//val appName = args(0)
val appName = "ReduceByKey"
val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[4]")
    .appName(appName)
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  println (s"\n Application is $appName \n")

  //println ("\nStarted at"); spark.sql("SELECT FROM_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ss') ").collect.foreach(println)
  val data = Seq(("Project", 1), ("Gutenberg's", 1), ("Alice's", 1),("Adventures", 1),("in", 1),("Wonderland", 1),("Project", 1),("Gutenberg's", 1),("in", 1),("Wonderland", 1),("Project", 1),("Gutenberg's", 1))

  println( "\n printing the list \n")
  data.foreach(println)

  val rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

  val rdd2=rdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)
  //rdd2.toDF.explain
  rdd2.toDF.collect.foreach(println)
  //Thread.sleep(60000)
  sys.exit()
 }
}
```

The POM file for this is

```
    <project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>spark</groupId>
<version>3.0</version>
<artifactId>ReduceByKey</artifactId>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>

<properties>
<spark.version>3.4.0</spark.version>
<maven.compiler.source>11.0.1</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11.0.1</maven.compiler.target>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<scala.major.version>2.13</scala.major.version>
<scala.minor.version>8</scala.minor.version>
<maven-scala-plugin.version>2.15.2</maven-scala-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<finalName>ReduceByKey</finalName>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven-scala-plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>compile</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<jvmArgs>
<jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
<jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
</jvmArgs>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.4.1</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>shade</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<filters>
<filter>
<artifact>*:*</artifact>
<excludes>
<exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
<exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
<exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
</excludes>
</filter>
</filters>
<transformers>
<transformer
implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
<mainClass>com.group.id.Launcher1</mainClass>
</transformer>
</transformers>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<!--<artifactId>scala</artifactId>-->
</project>
```

This is the output from maven

```
Compiling ReduceByKey
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< spark:ReduceByKey >--------------------------
[INFO] Building ReduceByKey 3.0
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ ReduceByKey ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (ANSI_X3.4-1968 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /data6/hduser/scala/ReduceByKey/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ ReduceByKey ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- scala:2.15.2:compile (default) @ ReduceByKey ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.13.8
[WARNING]  spark:ReduceByKey:3.0 requires scala version: 2.13.8
[WARNING]  org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parallel-collections_2.13:1.0.4 requires scala version: 2.13.6
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.java,**/*.scala,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ ReduceByKey ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (ANSI_X3.4-1968 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /data6/hduser/scala/ReduceByKey/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ReduceByKey ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0:test (default-test) @ ReduceByKey ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ ReduceByKey ---
[INFO] Building jar: /data6/hduser/scala/ReduceByKey/target/ReduceByKey.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- shade:3.4.1:shade (default) @ ReduceByKey ---
[INFO] Including org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.13.8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: /data6/hduser/scala/ReduceByKey/dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[WARNING] ReduceByKey.jar, scala-library-2.13.8.jar define 1 overlapping resource:
[WARNING]   - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /data6/hduser/scala/ReduceByKey/target/ReduceByKey.jar with /data6/hduser/scala/ReduceByKey/target/ReduceByKey-3.0-shaded.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.716 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-29T22:07:02+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 4 plugin(s)
[WARNING]
[WARNING]  * org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.4.1
[WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
[WARNING]
Completed compiling
Mon May 29 22:07:02 BST 2023 , Running in **local mode**
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

 Application is ReduceByKey

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.package$.Seq()Lscala/collection/immutable/Seq$;
        at ReduceByKey$.main(ReduceByKey.scala:23)
        at ReduceByKey.main(ReduceByKey.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1020)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I have tried to keep all artefacts in line with Spark 3.4.0 but somehow appears there is incompatibly of Scala versions?

Thanks

Comment: Where/how is it running? Indeed seems you compiled against Scala 2.13 but at runtime you are providing Scala 2.12. Or in your dependencies, there's something that expects 2.12 but doesn't look like it unless you removed some dependencies from the POM you show us.

Comment: Thanks. I compiled it  against Scala 2.12.17 and it worked fine

Comment: How do you specify Scala version at runtime with maven?

under properties I have

<properties>
<spark.version>3.4.0</spark.version>
<maven.compiler.source>11.0.1</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11.0.1</maven.compiler.target>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<scala.major.version>2.12</scala.major.version>
<scala.minor.version>17</scala.minor.version>
<maven-scala-plugin.version>2.15.2</maven-scala-plugin.version>
</properties>
Is this <maven-scala-plugin.version>?
Thanks

Comment: What maven command did you use? By default Maven does not run anything: it compiles, test and packages the project.

Comment: Well both MVN and SBT just create the uber jar file for Spark in this case with Scala version 2.12.17. The code is executed with ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit (Spark version 3.4.0),  which is compiled with scala-compiler-2.12.17.jar. So it works at the execution time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well both maven and SBT do just create the uber jar file for Spark in this case with Scala version 2.12.17. The code is executed with ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit (Spark version 3.4.0), which is compiled with scala-compiler-2.12.17.jar. So it works at the execution time.